# Run specific tests depending on flavor

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-productflavors

I have written few Espresso tests and I want to run specific test when one flavor is selected. For example I have tests for **Activity A** and **Activity B**, but in one of my flavors I can't reach **Activity B** (the launching button is hidden), so my test for **Activity B** will fail. Is there any way to define which tests should be run when specific flavor is selected?

Answer (score 2):

you can follow the instructions here
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing1

In general, the prefix of the test folder concat with the flavor name.

Comment: While technically correct, the link provided does not specifically discuss testing and is missing needed information.  This is a better link: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#create_instrumented_test_for_a_build_variant

Comment: It doesn't works for me. Whatever folder I created, `androidTestMyFlavor` for example, it depends on BuildVariant choosen. It not affected by folder name.